# Why the APK is not stored in my phone after i run the application?

Tags: android

I have two android projects. one of the projects  i run the app in the android studio through usb on my smartphone, and one project it saves the APK on the smartphone, while in the second project it does not saves the APK on the smartphone. 
what can i do to solve this, because im using google cloud messaging and when the APK is not install in the smartphone it cant get notifications.

---

**for example 
[in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxT4j.jpg)
you can see the application "GCMTest" stored in the smartphone**
**but in the other project it does not store the APK**

### how can i solve this?

**The Manifest of the project that does not install the APK in smartphone**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.world.bolandian.watchme"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

     <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
     -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
    <activity
        android:name="."
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.Register" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.Login" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"></action>
            <category android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

**Manifest of the second project that install the APK in the smartphone**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.world.bolandian.gcmtest">

<!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="com.world.bolandian.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.world.bolandian.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.world.bolandian.gcmtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check package names and please share your both application's manifest files.

Comment: i have edited my post, i added the manifest of the two projects